# angular 4 primeng table column header text in multiple lines

Tags: primeng

Using primeng table to display the data as grid.
Using below code to display testdate with date format.I would like to display the format part(YYYY-MM-dd) in second line of column.Please suggest

```
<p-column field="testdate" header="Test Date (YYYY-MM-dd)" [sortable]="true" 
[style]="{'width':'150px'}"></p-column>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ng-template`](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/templating) for that :

```
<p-column field="testdate" header="Test Date (YYYY-MM-dd)" [sortable]="true"
 [style]="{'width':'150px'}" let-testdate="rowData.testdate">
    <ng-template pTemplate="body">
        {{testate | date: 'YYYY-MM-dd'}}
    </ng-template>
</p-column>
```